# How to enable cache in crosswalk with cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I'm new in CrossWalk Or Cordova,I have add CrossWalkWebView in My Cordova and its working fine,But I want enable cache of CrossWalkWebView like other WebView do. So,How can we do this, what i have already do is:

- I have add CrossWalkWebView plugin in Cordova.
- I have add cache plugin in Cordova.

Tell me if i'm Wrong anywhere also tell what i should for enable cache.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask this at the [**Issues**](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cache%20) section of the **cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview** plugin.

Anyway, I personally wouldn't use this plugin because of its huge footprint, and adding another layer of dependencies to your Cordova app is simply asking for trouble. Additionally, this plugin was useful in the **Android 4** era, but since Android 5 the WebView is updated separately, so individual manufacturers can no longer mess with it. Now you have the same webview for all devices, this renders the Crosswalk plugin totally unnecessary.

Comment: what about caching enabling.